# Strongloop mysql connector ER_NO_DB_ERROR: No database selected

Tags: mysql, node.js, strongloop

I made a website with nodejs and strongloop. I used the mysql connector and tested the connection in Strongloop Arc.  The connection is OK. I created the models with the arc tool (discover models).  It was also OK.

But when I open the Strongloop API Explorer and do the test to get the data I Always get the error:

> "ER_NO_DB_ERROR: No database selected".

Comment: can you share the content of **datasources.json**?

Comment: {
  "db": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "mysql"
  },
  "dbAuction": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 3306,
    "database": "auctions",
    "password": "",
    "name": "dbAuction",
    "connector": "mysql",
    "user": "root"
  }
}

Comment: I'm using the dbAuction

Comment: have you check if **dbAuction** database has been created with required tables?

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed that your model was connected to dbAuction instead of db?
When using arc to add a model,  the 'datasource' should be 'dbAuction'.

You can also check the model-config.json in 'server/' directory. A property named 'dataSource' belongs to the model name like

```
"modelname" : {
  "dataSouce":"dbAuction"
  ...
},
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is the  model-config.json**

```
{
  "_meta": {
    "sources": [
      "loopback/common/models",
      "loopback/server/models",
      "../common/models",
      "./models"
    ],
    "mixins": [
      "loopback/common/mixins",
      "loopback/server/mixins",
      "../common/mixins",
      "./mixins"
    ]
  },
  "User": {
    "dataSource": "db"
  },
  "AccessToken": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "ACL": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "RoleMapping": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "Role": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "newModel": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": true
  },
  "Biedingen": {
    "dataSource": "dbAuction",
    "public": true
  },
  "Kavel": {
    "dataSource": "dbAuction",
    "public": true
  },
  "Gebruikers": {
    "dataSource": "dbAuction",
    "public": true
  },
  "Message": {
    "dataSource": "dbAuction",
    "public": true
  },
  "Veilingen": {
    "dataSource": "dbAuction",
    "public": true
  },
  "Sourcemessage": {
    "dataSource": "dbAuction",
    "public": true
  },
  "Veilingenkavels": {
    "dataSource": "dbAuction",
    "public": true
  },
  "Veilingsoorten": {
    "dataSource": "dbAuction",
    "public": true
  }
```

**and the datasources.json**

```
{
  "db": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "mysql"
  },
  "dbAuction": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 3306,
    "database": "auctions",
    "password": "",
    "name": "dbAuction",
    "connector": "mysql",
    "user": "root"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment since my reputation is too low..
I suggest you can change the 'mysql' in

```
"db": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "**mysql**"
```

into "memory" as it was initiated because the "db" is useful for some models while you changed wrongly so that 'db' cannot work well, which may lead to this problem.